# Could not create PDF: sh: wkhtmltopdf: command not found

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Just having some trouble with wkhtmltopdf. It works fine in command line but in PHP I keep getting this error:

```
Could not create PDF: sh: wkhtmltopdf: command not found.
```

It does work after a stop and restart of Apache, but it stops working after a couple of hours.

This is the current configuration:

```
phpwkhtmltopdf - latest version 
CentOS 5.10
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1
```

Answer (score 20):

Everything seems to work amazing if I declare the binary as well..

```
$options = array( ...,"binary" => "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf")
$pdf = new Pdf($options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install core library in system

```
Ubuntu 14.04 x64
Ubuntu 16.04 x64

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xvfb libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf
```