# Command was not found in your classpath error

Tags: java, windows, pdf, environment-variables, pdf-conversion

I use `wkhtmltopdf` in my Java app and when try to send HTTP request, I get "*wkhtmltopdf command was not found in your classpath. Verify its installation or initialize wrapper configurations with correct*" error. There are several fix for Linux e.g. [Could not create PDF: sh: wkhtmltopdf: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268022/could-not-create-pdf-sh-wkhtmltopdf-command-not-found), but I could not find any workaround for  `Windows`. I tried to add its installation path (`C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf`) to System Variables > Path section, but still the same error. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Are you using class [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (or `java.lang.Runtime`) to run `wkhtmltopdf` in your Java app?

Comment: @Abra How can I check that?

Comment: You say that you have a Java app and that you use `wkhtmltopdf` in your Java app. How do you use `wkhtmltopdf` in your Java app? `wkhtmltopdf` is a command line tool. How do you execute a command line tool from your Java app?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think the problem is related to environment variables rather than usage. So, I tried to add it to CLASSPATH by running `set CLASSPATH=.;C:\Progra~1\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe` on cmd or PowerShell. It throws error on PowerShell, but no error on cmd. STill, it is not added to CLASSPATH. SO, how can I add it? Should I add it manueally? **and**  should I add it until `bin`  directory as `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin` ?

Comment: I just try to run the following 2 options: `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin` and then `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf` ==> It is working. However, when trying to run the same command on `C:\` instead of `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin`, it throws **'wkhtmltopdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.** error. So, the problem is related to adding it to classpath. I added `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin` to the `Paths` on environment variables but does not make any sense. So, how to fix it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Any idea instead of edit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234031/discussion-between-abra-and-justice).

Comment: I joined chat but I am not sure if you have seen my messages?